# Information returned by getSkuDetails() for different versions of Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

With [Play Store v3.9.16](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html) Google introduced Billing API v3. The API's [`getSkuDetails(...)`](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) method returns a variety of information about the different products offered for sale. Unfortunately the type of information returned seems to depend on the installed version of Google Play.

So far, I have found 3 different versions of the returned data:

- On a device running Google Play v4.9.13 (and other ones with an even newer version), I get the following product listing, which includes all data that I was hoping for:

  ```
  {"title":"100 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#0360#","price_amount_micros":990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","productId":"vdm.ct.00001"}
  {"title":"250 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$1.99","type":"inapp","description":"#07oK#","price_amount_micros":1990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","productId":"vdm.ct.00002"}
  {"title":"500 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$2.99","type":"inapp","description":"#0Fce#","price_amount_micros":2990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","productId":"vdm.ct.00003"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Aqua\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#Wn3mF00P3Cw31IAh77iR1Gy\/BAqua#","price_amount_micros":990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","productId":"vdm.ct.00004"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Kiwi\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#Wn7me00t6VQWWaBL1fSm0jzOpKiwi#","price_amount_micros":990000,"price_currency_code":"USD","productId":"vdm.ct.00005"}
  ...
  ```
- On a device that runs Google Play v4.0.25 I only get:

  ```
  {"title":"100 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#0360#","productId":"vdm.ct.00001"}
  {"title":"250 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$1.99","type":"inapp","description":"#07oK#","productId":"vdm.ct.00002"}
  {"title":"500 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$2.99","type":"inapp","description":"#0Fce#","productId":"vdm.ct.00003"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Aqua\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#Wn3mF00P3Cw31IAh77iR1Gy\/BAqua#","productId":"vdm.ct.00004"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Kiwi\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"#Wn7me00t6VQWWaBL1fSm0jzOpKiwi#","productId":"vdm.ct.00005"}
  ...
  ```

  Notice, how "price_amount_micros" and "price_currency_code" are missing.
- On an even older device running Google Play v3.9.16, the list looks like this:

  ```
  {"title":"100 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"","productId":"vdm.ct.00001"}
  {"title":"250 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$1.99","type":"inapp","description":"","productId":"vdm.ct.00002"}
  {"title":"500 Hints (ColorTrek)","price":"$2.99","type":"inapp","description":"","productId":"vdm.ct.00003"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Aqua\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"","productId":"vdm.ct.00004"}
  {"title":"Level Pack \"Kiwi\" (50 Levels) (ColorTrek)","price":"$0.99","type":"inapp","description":"","productId":"vdm.ct.00005"}
  ...
  ```

  Notice how the "description" is an empty string for every product.

I have been able to find a [discussion thread that talks about the additional pricing info](https://code.google.com/archive/p/marketbilling/issues/93) where Comment #40 suggests that "price_amount_micros" and "price_currency_code" require Play Store v4.3.10.

I have not been able to find a similar discussion for the "description" field. Additionally, I'm a bit surprised that the field exists, but is empty...

This leaves me with the following questions:

- Is v4.3.10 the actual release that introduced "price_amount_micros" and "price_currency_code"?
- Is the empty "description" a bug in older versions of the Play Store?
- Or is there something I need to specifically do to have the description be included (like pick a locale or so)?
- If not, does anyone know which version of the Play Store does provide the correct info for the field?
- Is there some official source for release notes of the different Play Store versions that talk about changes to API behavior?
- Is there a trustworthy source for APKs of old Google Play Store versions?